# ScriptDb diminishing query

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that stores a large amount of data and then check that data for duplicates before storing more. Querying the database for each duplicate check causes the script to exceed max execution time so query the entire database and then just check against that query. The problem is that when I run through the duplicate check the query size diminishes to zero by the 4th pass, making it ineffective. Here is the code for the storing function and the duplicate check:

```
function ssToScriptDb_1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ah1c1zmu5vU_dEZJYVMzVnF6Y211cmJGdjZBUGFLQWc');  // **** create a function to prompt for the ID
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var columns = spreadsheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var keys = data[0];
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var allDb = db.query({});
  var items = [];
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var rowData = data[row];
    var item = {};
    for (var column = 0; column < keys.length; column++) {
      item[keys[column]] = rowData[column];  // ???? could I use this notation in place of the double for loops in timeClock?
    }
    item.visitDate = Utilities.formatDate(item.visitDate, "MST", "M/d/yyyy");

    // check to see if the item is already in the db
    if (dupCheck(db, allDb, item)) {
      items.push(item);
    }
    if (row % 1000 == 0) {
      Logger.log("row " + row + " completed at " + new Date() +"\n");
    }
  }

  var itemsLen = items.length;
  Logger.log('DB save start time ' + new Date() + '\n');
  var results = db.saveBatch(items, false);
  Logger.log('DB save end time ' + new Date() + '\n');
}

function dupCheck(db, query, item) {
  var count = 0;
  var querySize = query.getSize();
  var query2Size = db.query({}).getSize();
  while (query.hasNext()) {
    var ob = query.next();
    if (ob.ID == item.ID && ob.email == item.email && ob.visitDate == item.visitDate) {
      return false;
    }
    count++;
  }
  return true;
}
```

the first pass through `dupCheck()` in debug looks like this:
[image: dupCheck() pass 1]

notice that `querySize` is the query done before entering `dupCheck()` and query2Size is the same query done inside `dupCheck()`.

here is the second pass through `dupCheck()`:
[image: dupCheck() pass 2]

here is the 4th pass:
[image: dupCheck() pass 4]

again notice `querySize` vs `query2Size`.

I have no idea what is causing the original query to diminish but I can't call a query for each item, any idea what is causing this or have a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't realize `query.next()` was altering the query. To achieve what I needed I put the query results in an array and checked for duplicates against the array.